# Split string in Python into chunks with constant length, but right-aligned

Tags: python, string, slice

Basically, I have a string like "12345678" and need a list containing this information, but split into substrings of length 3. The problem is, that I need it to be right-aligned, so the output must be `['12', '345', '678']` and NOT `['123', '456', '78']`.
How do I best achieve with few code lines and preferably without additional imports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to try regular expressions, you can use the [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) function

```
>>> re.split(r"(...)(?=(?:\d\d\d)+$)","12345678")
['12', '345', '678']

>>> re.split(r"(...)(?=(?:\d\d\d)+$)","123")
['123']
```

---

**EDIT**

A better solution would be to use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
>>> re.findall(r"\d{1,3}(?=(?:\d{3})*$)", "12345")
['12', '345']

>>> re.findall(r"\d{1,3}(?=(?:\d{3})*$)", "123456")
['123', '456']

>>> re.findall(r"\d{1,3}(?=(?:\d{3})*$)", "1234567")
['1', '234', '567']
```

**What it does?**

- `\d{1,3}` Matches maximum of 3 characters, and minimum of 1 character.
- `(?=(?:\d{3})*$)` Positive look ahead. Ensures that the matched characters is followed by a multiple of 3 digits.

  - `(?:\d{3})` matches 3 digits.

---

You can use variables in the regex string to generate variable chunk of data.

**Example**

```
>>> $limit=4
>>> regex = r"\d{1,%d}(?=(?:\d{%d})*$)" %(limit,limit)
>>> re.findall(regex, "1234567")
['123', '4567']

>>> limit=3
>>> regex = r"\d{1,%d}(?=(?:\d{%d})*$)" %(limit,limit)
>>> re.findall(regex, "1234567")
['1', '234', '567']
```

Comment: Would you please add a short explanation about the regex parts? I will probably prefer your answer, but I don't really understand the regex you use yet.

Comment: And it would be interesting how I could reuse this code for variable chunk lengths.

Comment: @ByteCommander I have added an edit and a small explanation. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy enough to adapt the top answer from [How do I split a list into equally-sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python):

```
def chunks_rightaligned(l, n):
    orphan = len(l) % n
    if orphan:
        yield l[: orphan]         
    for i in range(orphan, len(l), n):
        yield l[i : i + n]
```

This yields a chunk of the remainder length first, then iterates over the indices in chunk-size steps starting from the orphan size rather than 0.

Demo:

```
>>> def chunks_rightaligned(l, n):
...     orphan = len(l) % n
...     if orphan:
...         yield l[: orphan]         
...     for i in range(orphan, len(l), n):
...         yield l[i : i + n]
... 
>>> list(chunks_rightaligned("12345678", 3))
['12', '345', '678']
>>> list(chunks_rightaligned("1234567", 3))
['1', '234', '567']
>>> list(chunks_rightaligned("123456", 3))
['123', '456']
```